# Avoiding constructor repetition in child's creation

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism, virtual

I got a parent class, and multiple child classes. I want to dynamically create child objects, of different classes depending on an input.

Assuming parent is declared this way:

```
class Parent {
public:
    Parent(int v);
};
```

`ChildOnE` and `ChildTwo` both inherits `Parent`. Is there a shortcut for the following :

```
shared_ptr<Parent> myObject;
switch(input) {
    case 1: {
        myObject = make_shared<ChildOne>(int v);
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        myObject = make_shared<ChildTwo>(int v);
        break;
    }
}
```

This is kind of heavy when dealing with more than two childs, especially when constructors are constructed the same way. Can't we somehow replicate the behaviour of a purely virtual constructor, so that childs all have to implement it, and then only change the class called, but not the parameters ?

**TL;DR** How can I shorten the above-mentionned example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a lookup table; something like:

```
using Ctor = shared_ptr<Parent>(int v);

static const std::map<int, Ctor *> ctors = {
    {1, (Ctor *)make_shared<ChildOne>}, // The cast chooses overload;
    {2, (Ctor *)make_shared<ChildTwo>}, // not sure is that necessary in such context
};

...
return (ctors.at(input))(v);
```

The great thing here is that while constructor is special and its address can’t be taken, `make_shared` is a regular function pointer to which can be passed around freely.

Comment: I saw the answer just now ^^ ! Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I needed. Didn't expect to receive an answer, I was starting to believe there was no shorter way.

Comment: Still have never learned about that use of the using keyword though ^^ so I'm digging on this side. If you got any reference link, that'd be greatly appreciated !

Comment: About what? `Ctor` in my example is just a type—a type of a function taking single `int` and returning `shared_ptr<Parent>`. Yes, in C++ functions have types too, not only pointers to them =)

Comment: yeah, I noticed my mistake rather quickly x). The concept of function types (especially to hold a constructor) is very clever o:

Comment: I just don’t like LPFNPCSTRCB-like types, preferring to specify pointerness at the usage place. Also no function pointer can’t point to the constructor itself, only to some wrapper function (because constructors are really special in C++).

Comment: Is there a way, not to use an empty constructor on Parent ? (which is required by make_shared here)